# SDL2 Segfault in SDL_FillRect

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, sdl-2

Terminal output:

```
    > ./a.out 
    bla1
    Speicherzugriffsfehler
```

Speicherzugriffsfehler means basically Segmentation fault in german.

When i used global variables, or copypasted the code in the functions into main it just worked. I have no idea why its broken.

Compiled on Linux Mint 16 with: g++ sdl.cpp -lSDL2

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

using namespace std;

bool init_SDL(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *windowSurface);
void close_SDL(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *image);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *windowSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *image = NULL;

    if(!init_SDL(window, windowSurface)){
        cout << "Failed to initialize SDL" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "bla1" << endl;
        SDL_FillRect(windowSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(windowSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        cout << "bla2" << endl;
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        cout << "bla3" << endl;
        SDL_Delay(2000);
    }
    close_SDL(window, image);

    EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool init_SDL(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *windowSurface){
    bool success = true;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        cout << "SDL failed to initialize! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        success = false;
    }
    else{
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(window == NULL){
            cout << "Failed to create window! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
            success = false;
        }
        else{
            windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        }
    }
    return success;
}

void close_SDL(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *image){
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return;
}
```

Comment: @Can you share the call stack of your program(using gdb), at the time of segmentation-fault.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution on reddit.
This solved it:

```
bool init_SDL(SDL_Window *&window, SDL_Surface *&windowSurface)
```

I needed to pass the pointers by reference, because the pointers itself get manipulated in the functions. Otherwise they would still point to null in main.